# how to get Event click object when handler has arguments

Tags: javascript, html

In the following example, if we add *handler* to `addEventListener` without any args, then `Event click` object is automatically passed as argument to the *handler*.

```
<table id="outside">
    <tr><td id="t1"> one </td></tr>
    <tr><td id="t2"> two </td></tr>
</table>

<script>
    function modifyText(e,text) 
    {
        console.log(e); // logs => click clientX=100, clientY=21
    }

    // add event listener to table
    var el = document.getElementById("outside");

        el.addEventListener("click", modifyText, false);                     //method 1
    //  el.addEventListener("click", function(){modifyText("four")}, false); //method 2
</script>
```

But if you pass any args to the *handler*, then `Event click` object is not passed. How to get the `Event click` obj along with args in *handler*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use an anonymous function, `event` is auto passed in:

```
el.addEventListener("click", function(event){
    //event is passed
    modifyText("four") //add another param here to pass 'event' along with your param
}, false);
```

If you specify a function as the callback, you get the default params, as above (`event` being the first one)

You'll have to pass it along to your function via a second parameter if you want more params.

Comment: bingo! it worked. `el.addEventListener("click", function(event){modifyText(event,"four")}`

Comment: @aj_blk -- Be sure to accept the answer when ya can :D

Comment: i wanna but SO says wait 4 mins